# App doesn´t work on device

Tags: android, web-services, debugging

I have created and app that read data from a web service. But when I was trying to run it on a real device. It does not work. It just stopped on the first screen and does not show anything but the title of the app. 
 It seems like can load the data from the webserice. Something I need to configure?

The app have internet permission, but it does not need right now, because the service is runnning locally. Any idea or similar experience?

**The main class:**

```
public class Dashboard extends FragmentActivity implements OnClickListener, ClientDetailActivity.OnHeadlineSelectedListener {

Button btnConociendoAlCliente, btnMaterialDeApoyo, btnMaterialPromocional;

LinearLayout panelConociendoAlCliente, panelMaterialDeApoyo,
        panelMaterialPromocional, panelFragment;
Fragment listFragment;
ClientDetailActivity clientDetailActivity;

private ListView list;


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    initComponents();
}

public void initComponents() {

    panelFragment = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelFragment);
    panelMaterialDeApoyo = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelMaterialDeApoyo);
    panelMaterialPromocional = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.panelMaterialPromocional);

    panelFragment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    panelMaterialDeApoyo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    panelMaterialPromocional.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    btnMaterialDeApoyo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMaterialDeApoyo);
    btnMaterialPromocional = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMaterialPromocional);
    btnConociendoAlCliente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnConociendoAlCliente);

    btnConociendoAlCliente.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMaterialDeApoyo.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnMaterialPromocional.setOnClickListener(this);

    clientDetailActivity = new ClientDetailActivity();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.listFragment, clientDetailActivity);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

My web service just gather from the db date about client. This is the code:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet del = new HttpGet(ruta + "s");
        del.setHeader("content-type", "application/json");

        try {
            HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(del);
            String respStr = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
            JSONArray respJSON = new JSONArray(respStr);
            clientes = new String[respJSON.length()];

            for (int i = 0; i < respJSON.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject obj = respJSON.getJSONObject(i);

                // Log.e("nombre", idCli);
                ClienteDetallado clienteDetallado = new ClienteDetallado();

                try {
                    clienteDetallado.setCod_Medico(obj.getString("Cod_Medico"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    clienteDetallado.setCod_Medico("N/A");
                }

                try {
                    clienteDetallado.setNombre(obj.getString("Nombre"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    clienteDetallado.setNombre("N/A");
                }

                try {
                    clienteDetallado.setApellido(obj.getString("Apellido"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    clienteDetallado.setApellido("N/A");
                }


                clienteDetallados.add(clienteDetallado);
            }

            MyOwnArrayAdapter myOwnArrayAdapter = new MyOwnArrayAdapter(getActivity(), clienteDetallados);
            list.setAdapter(myOwnArrayAdapter);

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.e("ServicioRest", "Error en listar!", ex);
        }

        return view;
    }
```

It´s located in the method getView() of the fragment above. 
There is the URL that is used by the HttpClient class.
In the emulator, all works fine. But not in the device.

Thanks!

Comment: can you upload the code please ?

Comment: I updated the post to include some code.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what your webservice is, where is it, how you are connecting to it from emulator and device.

Comment: Updated again answering your questions Mr. Morrison. Thanks for answering.